# Применить стиль к программно созданному View

Tags: android

Имеется файл со стилем, его содержимое:

```
<style name="myStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Создаю в java файле новый textView:
TextView tv = new TextView();

Как программно применить указанный стиль к созданному View? 
Какие методы использовать?

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос более чем развернут

Answer (score 2):

```
final Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myStyle);
View view = new View(contextThemeWrapper);
```

Comment: попробовал ВАш вариант, не стилизует (

Answer (score 0):

Определить в 'res/values/attrs.xml':

```
<attr name="customTextViewStyle" format="reference"/>
```

В 'res/values/style.xml' добавить к вашей теме:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="@attr/customTextViewStyle">@style/myStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Использовать так:

```
new TextView (context, null, android.R.attr.customTextViewStyle);
```

Answer (score 0):

я в свое время пару дней убил на поиск ответа. Не нашел решения конкретно такого подхода. но нашел немного другой подход:  
Создайте layout с нужным View в корне, примените к нему стиль в этом layout файле.  
Когда нужно создать View программно, используйте код вроде этого:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.styled_text_view, null);
```

Ну и, на всякий случай пример `styled_text_view.xml`:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/featured"
    style="@style/MenuItemTextStyle" />
```

Comment: @metalurgus попробуйте мой вариант решения, который я привел в ответе